# Best way to unit test jsf 2.0 Managed Bean

Tags: java, jsf-2, managed-bean

What is the most effective way of unit testing JSF 2.0 managed beans. I have seen JSFUnit from JBoss but it looks like its for testing the components in the facelets pages but not the managed beans themselves.

I want to find a way to effectively unit test only the managed beans.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Set up your managed beans so that all their dependencies are injected as managed properties via setters. Then you can manually inject mocks or stubs in your unit tests.

Comment: I've tried something like that, but, during the test I get the following error ''Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/ejb/EJBException", cos my MBs have some EJBs injected and the concrete classes are provided on runtime. Have you figured an way to fix that?

Comment: @Jaumzera: you'll need a Java EE implementation to be loaded at test-runtime, not just the API - it's only for compiling against.

Answer (score 3):

[JSFUnit](http://www.jboss.org/jsfunit) is another alternative